# Please delete the "best-practies" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, burninate-request

As we all know, [Jeff Atwood has banned the best-practices tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). I had untagged a question fairly recently with the "mistyped" tag "best-practies", and just now I saw several recently asked questions with the tag. Please, could someone delete the tag so that it isn't used *again*?

Comment: It sounds like a Meta 'best-practice' to delete this tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agree: this meta typo tag (ugh) has been burninated.